# HOWTO: SQLite with EntityFramework and Code-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to create an embedded SQLite database on the fly with the EF however, I can't get it to work, the database file is never getting created.

I have EF 4.2 and latest version SQLite

Here is what I have

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider"
           invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=test.db;Version=3;New=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**DB initializer (to put some content in)**

```
class PageDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PageDB>
{
    protected override void Seed(PageDB context)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            WebPage page = new WebPage() { Name = "Page" + (i + 1) };
            context.Pages.Add(page);
        }
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
class PageDB : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<WebPage> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

And finally in the main()

```
Database.SetInitializer( new PageDbInitializer() );
```

I believe I have some steps missing, but can't find them out.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you end up doing? did you use the devart provider or find another solution?

Comment: @StellaMusik I ended up using SQLExpress for the time being, but you can always use model or database first with SQLlite

Comment: @PierlucSS facing same issue. I don't want to use Devart's so apparently its gonna be model-first

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`System.Data.SQLite` is in current version only EFv1 compatible provider ([1](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), [2](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/features.wiki)). It means it doesn't have EFv4 (EFv4.2 is wrapper around EFv4) features including database creation and deletion (check `DbProviderServices` differences for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderservices_methods%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)). Because of that you cannot use automatic database creation with code first when working with SQLite. You must create database and all tables manually.

As an alternative you can use different provider for SQLite. For example [Devart's SQLite provide](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/)r claims it supports EFv4 and 4.1 and thus database creation.

Comment: Since this is an old post, do you know if this is still a valid answer? I am currently trying to find information about this and in my research progress, it does seem like this still holds true (but I am not sure)

Comment: I can verify that I even still cannot create database with current sqlite provider.

Comment: @user3141326: Can you try EF Core (aka EF 7)? It should have build in provider for SQLite.

Answer (score 15):

Check this out:

https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst

Also available as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.CodeFirst/)

It adds some DB Initializers to your ptoject, such as `SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists`

Here's the example from the web site:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("ConnectionStringName") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>(
            Database.Connection.ConnectionString, modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Current version (1.5.1.25) doesn't need the connection string passed into the SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists constructor though, just the model builder.