# SQLite CreateDatabase not supported error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sqlite, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, system.data.sqlite

I'm using Entity Framework 4.2 CF with SQLite, but when i try to launch the application i got "CreateDatabase is not supported by the provider" error. This is my model mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region NewsMapping

            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().ToTable("news");
            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID").HasColumnOrder(0);
            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(x => x.Status).HasColumnName("STATUS");
            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(x => x.NewsTitle).HasColumnName("NEWS_TITLE");
            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(x => x.Content).HasColumnName("CONTENT_1");
            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(x => x.IsImportant).HasColumnName("IS_IMPORTANT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(x => x.OrderNumber).HasColumnName("ORDER_NUMBER");
            modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(x => x.CreateDate).HasColumnName("CREATE_DATE");
            #endregion

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
```

What is wrong in this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i found the solution, the provider doesn't support "Database Creation", so i had to initialize it empty:

```
public EkosContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<EkosContext>(null);
        }
```

Comment: How did you apply the model?

Answer (score 9):

Nothing is wrong in the code. The error says exactly what is going on. Your EF provider for SQLite (`System.Data.SQLite`) [doesn't provide database creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142498/howto-sqlite-with-entityframework-and-code-first) so you must create database and all tables manually before you launch the application.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error for `EF 6.1.3` and `System.Data.Sqlite 1.0.103` because I did not specify the location of the database file properly in my `web.config` file.

To fix the problem I moved the database file to `App_Data` and changed my connection string to `connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|databaseName;Version=3;"`

Comment: That actually solved my problem. Also creating the missing `App_Data` folder.

Answer (score 0):

As been because of the wrong path of my sqlitedb for me in the web.config, as simple and stupid that annoying.